# Is namespace-`static` still deprecated in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deprecation of the static keyword… no more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726570/deprecation-of-the-static-keyword-no-more)

In C++2003, namespace-`static` is deprecated:

> `[C++03: 7.3.1.1/2]:` The use of the `static` keyword is deprecated when
>   declaring objects in a namespace scope (see annex D); the
>   *unnamed-namespace* provides a superior alternative.

I can't find where any such clause exists in C++2011 (suggesting undeprecation), and `7.1.1` doesn't seem to prohibit namespace-`static` (and if it had, this would suggest that the feature had been finally removed from the language); however, neither case is listed in `C.2` (which itemises significant differences between 2003 and 2011).

Was namespace-`static` undeprecated or not?

Comment: How on earth is this off-topic?!

Comment: Not sure, but I'd like to know the answer as well

Comment: Is this an update to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977252/why-unnamed-namespace-is-a-superior-alternative-to-static

Comment: @WillBickford: Not deliberately, and they are distinct questions.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde: Woo, found it!

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered.  The removal of the deprecation was deliberate, [and was approved at the November, 2010 meeting](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1012).

Comment: @Keith: That one is "why was it undeprecated", whereas this one is "was it undeprecated". Still... dammit.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Yes, but the accepted answer links to the definitive statement that it was deliberately undeprecated.  (And I didn't see that you had posted an answer.)

Comment: @Keith: Doesn't make the questions identical. (Though I wouldn't have posted this one had I spotted that one already. Because, if nothing else, my question would have been indirectly answered!)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Undeprecating namespace-`static` was [proposed and accepted for n3296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3296.html#FI6):

> **ID:** FI 6
>   **Ref:** D.2 [depr.static] ¶ Paragraph 1
>   **Comment:** The use of static in namespace scope should not be deprecated. Anonymous namespaces are not a sufficient replacement for the functionality.
>   **Proposed Resolution:** *Strike [depr.static] completely.*
>   **Owner:** CWG
>   **Issue:** 1012
>   **Disposition:** *ACCEPTED*

In fact, clause C (on compatibility) does not list any changes made to clause D (on deprecation), so it's hard to tell "at a glance". **But, no, namespace-`static` is no longer deprecated in C++11.**