# Should I use static or a namespace?

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

I have a dedicated HW register header file, I have created a namespace, like this, which holds all of my HW register addresses:

```
namespace{
 const uint32_t Register1                    = (0x00000000);
 const uint32_t Register2                    = (0x00000004);
 const uint32_t Register3                    = (0x00000008);
 const uint32_t Register4                    = (0x0000000c);
}
```

Is this considered better than using:

```
 static const uint32_t Register1             = (0x00000000);
 static const uint32_t Register2             = (0x00000004);
 static const uint32_t Register3             = (0x00000008);
 static const uint32_t Register4             = (0x0000000c);
```

I guess the point of namespaces is that we don't pollute the global namespace.  Is that right?

I have one .cpp, which uses the header file.

Comment: C++11 I'd use a strongly typed enum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The two are essentially equivalent.**

The global-`static` method was deprecated in C++03 (`[depr.static]`) in favour of unnamed namespaces, but then [undeprecated by C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460248/560648) because everybody realised [there is no objective benefit of one over the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4726710/560648) in the general case.

However, for this, you may find an `enum` or `enum class` to be more manageable and idiomatic.

Answer (score 3):

These two are 100% equivalent, and they're also 100% equivalent to omitting both `namespace` and `static`:

```
const uint32_t Register1                    = (0x00000000);
const uint32_t Register2                    = (0x00000004);
const uint32_t Register3                    = (0x00000008);
const uint32_t Register4                    = (0x0000000c);
```

The reason is simple - a `const` variable is `static` unless you explicitly declare it `extern`.

However, this looks like something where using an enumeration would be preferable.