# C++ reader function design: helper functions, class, private, over-engineering?

Tags: c++, filereader, private-members

In C++, I would like to implement a reader function, i.e., method that is only executed once, returns something and then goes away. The reading process is a little complicated, so I thought I best split the thing up into a `read(filename)` and several helper functions. To make sure they're not accidentally accessed, I thought I wrap this whole thing in a stateless class and mark those helper functions as private. This, however, creates the code overhead of having to create an instance of the reader class first, and then call `read(filename)` on it. Alright, so let's create a helper function creates an instance of said class, calls `read(filename)`, dumps it and returns the read output.

```cpp
class Reader
{
public:
Reader();

virtual
~Reader();

OutputData
read(const std::string & fileName);

private:
helper1_();
helper2_();
helper3_();
};

OutputData
ReadIt(const std::string & fileName)
{
Reader r();
OutputData out = r.read(fileName);
return out;
}
```

Hm, that smells a bit over-engineered. What's your take on this?

Comment: `static void Reader::read()` solves the problem of having to create `Reader` object.

Comment: The main overhead is actually the virtual destructor, which is not needed and which introduces a pointer to the VT.  Otherwise instantiating the class is only 1 unused byte.

Comment: @Robᵩ up until C++11, static members were apparently deemed inferior to the namespace approach, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977252/why-unnamed-namespace-is-a-superior-alternative-to-static. Thanks for the hint though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds fine, but if all you need is a set of independent helper functions with no state, it may be a better idea to just use free functions and hide them int he implementation. A way to do this is to put all the helpers in an anonymous namespace in the implementation file.

Header file:

```
namespace Reader {

OutputData reatIt(const std::string& filename);

} // Reader namespace
```

Implementation file

```
namespace Reader {

namespace {

void helper1_() { .... }
void helper2_() { .... }
void helper3_() { .... }

} // anonymous namespace

readIt(const std::string& filename) {
  // use helpers here. Client code will never know.
}

} // Reader namespace
```

Comment: When splitting the code in `cpp` and `hpp`, another possibility would be to just not declare the helper functions in the `hpp`. Not sure if this is considered good practice though.

Comment: @nico  that is what I propose here, so the caller code has no knowledge of the helpers.

Comment: So what's the anonymous namespace needed for?

Comment: @Nico it means that the symbols corresponding to the code in the anonymous namespace are not available to users of the object file compiled from the `.cpp` file. The anonymous namespace hides the symbols so one cannot use the functions outside of the `.cpp`.