# What does it mean by "indirectly declaring a namespace within another namespace"?

Tags: c++, c++14

[basic.link] paragraph 4 in the C++14 Standard:

> An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly
>   within an unnamed namespace has internal linkage. All other namespaces
>   have external linkage. A name having namespace scope that has not been
>   given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing
>   namespace if it is the name of ...

What does it mean by "indirectly declaring a namespace within another namespace" above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linkage of symbols within anonymous namespace within a regular namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181059/linkage-of-symbols-within-anonymous-namespace-within-a-regular-namespace)

Comment: @Alex I cannot see how the answers to that question answer this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means a namespace nested inside an unnamed namespace, so either a namespace declared as a member of an unnamed namespace, or declared as a member of a namespace declared as a member of an unnamed namespace, or so on.

Comment: But what's the difference between "directly" and "indirectly"?

Comment: @NeilKirk AFAIK "indirectly" just means not a direct member, but a member of a member, or so on. But I'm ready to be proven wrong.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the difference between a namespace declared, direcltly versus indirectly, within another namespace.

Comment: @Alexander Did you see my comment to NeilKirk?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I'm still not convinced about your answer.